# Why is this field undefined?

Tags: javascript, html

After I submit my form and return to the page, the field that does the submit displays the unwanted text "undefined":

[image]

How can I lose the text "undefined"? I do absolutely nothing to make it appear. This is the HTML:

```
<span class="small60">Nummer: 
<input onkeypress="javascript:searchWithEnter('Oversikt','fastsearch')" 
       title="<%=mouseOverFast %>" type="text" size="40" name="fastsearch">
```

The script:

```
function searchWithEnter(action, command) {
    if (window.event && window.event.keyCode == 13) {
        document.actionForm.action.value = 'Oversikt';
        document.actionForm.actionCommand.value = 'fastsearch';
        document.actionForm.submit();
        disableAll();

    }
}
```

Comment: How are you populating the input?

Comment: Show the JS code `searchWithEnter` might assign something to `this.value`, but what it assigns might be `undefined`

Comment: post your searchWithEnter() function.. so that we can help

Comment: I posted that code but that's not it. Not even an onload at the bodytag to clear the field is working. Why is it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`searchWithEnter` tries to set the value of the field with an undefined variable.

EDIT: I don't see a value attribute for the input.

Comment: You are making a huge assumption here without seeing any of the code. It is a reasonable educated guess, but that's all it is.